# How to implement summation (∑) on 3d xarray data?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, python-xarray

Assume I have two variables in a dataset in xarray format as follow:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
pre= 10 * np.random.rand(5, 4, 10)
temp = 15 * np.random.rand(5, 4, 10)
time = pd.date_range("2014-01", periods=10, freq='MS')

ds = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars=dict(
        temperature=(["lat", "lon", "time"], temp),
        precipitation=(["lat", "lon", "time"], pre),
    ),
    coords={"lon": [25, 25.5, 26, 26.5], "lat": [42.5, 43, 43.5, 44, 44.5], "time": time},
    attrs=dict(description="Weather related data."),)
```

I appreciate any help on how to calculate the following formula:

[image]

So far I am trying to solve it as follow:

```
ds_pre_std = ds.pre.std(dim="time", skipna=True)

Z1= xr.zeros_like(ds.pre)

for k in range(len(ds.time)):
    Z[k, :, :] = np.sum(ds.pre[k, :, :] - ds.temp[k, :, :]) ** 2 / ds_pre_std


Z2= xr.zeros_like(ds.pre)
for k in range(len(ds.time)):
    Z2[k, :, :] = np.sum(ds.pre[k, :, :] - ds.pre.mean("time")) ** 2 / ds_pre_std 

Z = Z1 / Z2
```

But I am sure I am far a way from the correct results, particularly for the sum function which I think I have to define the first and last value based on the formula!

Comment: Note that `np.sum` has an `axis` keyword. THis should help you a lot to solve your problem. For more information, please read the Numpy documentation.

Comment: There's no need to use `np.sum`; there's already a `sum` method on a dataset, which takes a `dim` arg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clear example.

If I'm interpreting the example correctly — and we want to reduce over the time dimension — then here's the first half, and the second half follows exactly.

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: import pandas as pd
   ...: import xarray as xr
   ...: pre= 10 * np.random.rand(5, 4, 10)
   ...: temp = 15 * np.random.rand(5, 4, 10)
   ...: time = pd.date_range("2014-01", periods=10, freq='MS')
   ...:
   ...: ds = xr.Dataset(
   ...:     data_vars=dict(
   ...:         temperature=(["lat", "lon", "time"], temp),
   ...:         precipitation=(["lat", "lon", "time"], pre),
   ...:     ),
   ...:     coords={"lon": [25, 25.5, 26, 26.5], "lat": [42.5, 43, 43.5, 44, 44.5], "time": time},
   ...:     attrs=dict(description="Weather related data."),)

In [2]: ds
Out[2]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (lat: 5, lon: 4, time: 10)
Coordinates:
  * lon            (lon) float64 25.0 25.5 26.0 26.5
  * lat            (lat) float64 42.5 43.0 43.5 44.0 44.5
  * time           (time) datetime64[ns] 2014-01-01 2014-02-01 ... 2014-10-01
Data variables:
    temperature    (lat, lon, time) float64 0.5981 11.84 11.35 ... 4.074 12.49
    precipitation  (lat, lon, time) float64 7.012 7.678 9.634 ... 2.729 5.944
Attributes:
    description:  Weather related data.

In [3]: numer_1 = (ds['precipitation']) - ds['temperature']) ** 2

In [4]: denom_1 = ds['precipitation'].std('time')

In [5]: numer_1 / denom_1
Out[5]:
<xarray.DataArray (lat: 5, lon: 4)>
array([[6.65870313, 0.01847954, 1.35175245, 1.33186654],
       [4.37142192, 2.57042848, 5.10478184, 7.57213791],
       [0.33377772, 4.65275033, 0.05615346, 0.10104126],
       [2.05970793, 3.75681053, 9.89674346, 0.80563933],
       [3.57408137, 0.11641076, 4.55715038, 0.03830404]])
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float64 25.0 25.5 26.0 26.5
  * lat      (lat) float64 42.5 43.0 43.5 44.0 44.5
```

...and similar for the second half.

Notably, there's no need to use python loops nor numpy functions — this sort of operation is well within xarray's comfort zone.

---

Edit: in response to your question, is the denominator (although you write numerator, so maybe I'm confused):

```
In [22]: (ds['precipitation'] - ds['precipitation'].mean('time')) / ds['precipitation'].std('time')

Out[22]:
<xarray.DataArray 'precipitation' (lat: 5, lon: 4, time: 10)>
array([[[-0.98966504, -0.11198979, -0.75832633,  1.3114296 ,
          1.14629021,  0.63349046, -1.07008682,  1.16006701,
         -0.25235464, -1.13866263]]])
Coordinates:
  * lon      (lon) float64 25.0 25.5 26.0 26.5
  * lat      (lat) float64 42.5 43.0 43.5 44.0 44.5
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2014-01-01 2014-02-01 ... 2014-10-01
```

Comment: Thanks @Maximilian, but how about the numerator (the second part that you didn't mention). Here, each "time" step should be subtracted from the mean. Should I use a loop in this part?

Comment: I added a suggestion. If that's not correct, could you show how it's wrong? Definitely no loops required!

Comment: Thanks again @Maximilian, the second part seems correct. But now I think the first part is not correct, and we should not get the mean, because based on the formula each time step of `pre` should be subtracted from each time step of `temp`. So it should be like this
`numer_1 = (ds['precipitation']) - ds['temperature']) ** 2`
if you agree please confirm my comment and edit your answer, then I could accept your answer. 
anyway, as you mentioned there is no need for a loop :)